# Is it worth to get a Bianchi Caurus 909 and rebuild some parts?

Tags: road-bike, commuter

I'm planning to get a Bianchi Caurus 909 2nd hand for city bike and some long rides (30 km average) whenever i want to visit another city for example. The thing is if it worths to get the bike and change the gears, maybe the brakes, handlebar plus the maintenance. I've asked a bicycle guy from my city and he said it would cost something like 80 euros to clean and change its parts that i've mentioned on top.

I'd like to convert this:
[image]

To this:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Good decision to replace the triathlon hack with normal handlebar. Is the bike going to cost you anything besides the service?

Comment: Thanks for answer. Yes, it cost like 100 euro I guess.

Comment: Looks like a decent bike.  Note that it is *old*, and replacement parts may be a little sparse.

Comment: Gorgeous bike - Do it!  N+1 !     Sadly that's an opinion - perhaps this would be better in the [chat] where things are much less structured.

Comment: A final price of 250 for this bike, working, I say would be OK. Hardest part to find, if the seller doesnt have them laying around, is the downtube shifters indexed for 7 speed. 80 for the repair maintenance seems a bit optimistic. Also pedals?, tyres? saddle? How are the wheels? The little bike pedal going trhough the spokes is not a good signal. I'd ask him for all the stock parts that are not mounted, he seems to have a big bike collection there, maybe he kept them...

Comment: @gaurwraith he has lot of bikes, most of them recycled from NL and Germany. Wheels are ok. Saddle a bit loose but ok. Pedals are included (cheaper one)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From economical standpoint, rebuilding bicycles is almost always unreasonable. For the same amount of money spent on replacement components, it is often possible to buy a new decent bicycle of the same or better level, thus saving workshop time.

If, however, money is not a deciding factor for starting a rebuild, then the answer depends on whether you like spending your time with bike tinkering, and have no other better/enjoyable things to do. If you do enjoy working on your bikes, restoring old things, or want to learn new skills and things, then go for it — wrenching on a bike is often a rewarding experience.

Comment: Thanks! I'll get a road-touring bike brand new instead :)

Answer (score 3):

If it’s ‘worth it’ to you depends on many things.

You’ll have to figure out what it will cost in terms of money and time. You’ll probably have to spend time researching component compatibility, installation and adjustment. You may also need to buy special tools.

Start by figuring out what needs replacing immediately, and what you’ll have to or want to replace eventually, and add up the cost. Don’t forget things like bar tape and a new chain.

You should also figure out if there is anything that will be a real pain - like 27” wheels instead of 700c.

If you enjoy repairing and refurbishing bikes by all means go for it. You will end up with a cool bike.

Answer (score 2):

Provided you do the work yourself, used bikes almost always work out cheaper than new. If you are going to rely on a bike shop to do the work needed, new (or new new) will be cheaper - labour is expensive.

Parts can also add up very quickly, especially if buying at MRRP. Shopping online, learning whats compatible with what and ordering the parts based on low priced deals can save a fortune. On an older bike, the range available online my be harder to come buy in online shops, and you may be forced to pay MRRP at the LBS.

In summary - if your a tinkerer who loves to learn and experiment and do things yourself, an old bike will save money and get you a better bike than buying new. If you are the type that gets the LBS to repair your punctures, an old bike could be buying a who lot of expensive trouble.